# How do I install pepper-flash on Chromium?

Tags: software-installation, flash, chromium

I have Chromium web browser on my Lubuntu 13.04 (pre-installed).  I use LX Terminal (pre-installed) to write commands. I am trying to download flash player on Chromium using instructions on this [site](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
```

After typing in my password, this worked.
Now

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I didn't need to type in my password, as I continued on the same terminal, but got W:/ and E:/ fetch file errors

```
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

I continued on the same terminal despite the fetch file errors... and they said `pepflashplugin-installer could not be found`.

Is the last error because of fetch file errors, or because I need to download `pepflash-plugin-installer` somewhere? Or is it because of something else?

I cannot download the Chrome browser, and not looking to use flash player on my Firefox web browser (installed using lubuntu software center).

Comment: 13.04 is no longer supported, and, likely because of that, there are no packages for it in the PPA.

Comment: @mikewhatever are you aware that this was asked in october, right?

Comment: @Braiam Yep, though not sure why it matters now. Trying to apply the PPA solution doesn't work, and those that come here should know why, don't you think?

Comment: Navigate to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder then open `pipelight*.list` file with your text editor and replace `raring` with `precise` and run `sudo apt-get update` then run `sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer`

Answer (score 3):

Pepper Flash is now in Ubuntu repositories (14.04). Install it like:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Comment: This should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Now Pepper Flash plugin with the regular Flash has been moved to Ubuntu Partner repository.

Both Flash players can be installed by

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

after the Canonical Partner repository is enabled in Software & Updates.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Chrome Browser you don't need to install pepper-flash. You can use command line option redirecting pepper plugin path like

```
 chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=`grep -i version /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/manifest.json | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'`
```

should work.

You can make a launcher script like

chromium.sh

```
  #!/bin/bash
  chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=`grep -i version /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/manifest.json | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'`
```

set execution bit

```
chmod +x chromium.sh
```

Comment: Get the following error: `grep: /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/manifest.json: No such file or directory`

Comment: @KarlMorrison
You have to install **chrome** browser beforehand in order to use pepper plugin in **chromium**

Comment: @kenn i already have a chromium browser and i am also getting the same error

Comment: @Eka  what is output of  `locate libpepflashplayer.so` ?

Comment: @kenn noting . it just execute

Comment: @Eka then you don't have **chrome** web browser installed in your system. You need **chrome**'s **libpepflashplayer.so** library file. The easiest way to have it is to install **chrome** browser. Difference between **chrome** and **chromium** is that chromium is open source while chrome is closed source.

Answer (score 0):

Install the PPA from here: https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/pepper-flash and use Chromium. A quick summary of the steps are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

.. it then installs..

```
echo ". /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh" | sudo tee -a /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

When you restart chromium, you should be using the new flash plugin!