# Can't install pepperflashplugin-nonfree in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: software-installation, 14.10

After I upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.10 (everything was normal during the upgrade), every time when I try to install pepperflashplugin-nonfree installation hangs at 80% and remains so for hours (and maybe days) until I cancel the action or until I shutdown my PC:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  ttf-dejavu ttf-xfree86-nonfree
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pepperflashplugin-nonfree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11,1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 70,7 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package pepperflashplugin-nonfree.
(Reading database ... 279064 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.7ubuntu1) ...

Progress: [ 80%] [###############################################...........]
```

After this when I try to update my system or install something else I get the error with  held broken packages. I can get rid by error only running:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

And than again I can install anything excepting pepperflashplugin-nonfree.

So, my question is: what can be wrong with the installation of pepperflashplugin-nonfree? Why it doesn't want to finish? I mention that I have a good internet connection.

Comment: you don't have to install pepperflash, you can use `chrome` peper plugin with `chromium` http://askubuntu.com/questions/369023/how-do-i-install-pepper-flash-on-chromium/427255#427255

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using a Chromium based web browser in Ubuntu, you may find that the Adobe Flash Player installed from Ubuntu Software Center does not work all the time.

Because ‘Aura’ for Linux, which replaces GTK+, lacks coded support for NPAPI plugins, the “old” Adobe plugin in Ubuntu repositories does no longer play Flash content in Chromium based web browser.

As a workaround, you can use the ‘Pepper Flash’ which is bundled with Google Chrome that provides the latest Adobe Flash Player for Linux.

[click here](http://apt://pepperflashplugin-nonfree) to bring up Ubuntu Software Center and click the install button
This will install the package “Pepperflashplugin-nonfree“, which will download Chrome from Google, unpack it and make the included Pepper Flash Player available for use with Chromium.and this will reduce your terminal error risk also.

After that, relaunch Chromium browser and Flash should now work. If not, close the browser and run below command in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) to tell the plugin location:

`sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install`

That’s it. Enjoy!