# How do I play swf files?

Tags: chromium, swf

I downloaded Ubuntu Unity onto my [Chromebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook). I use Chromium as a browser since Google Chrome is messed up. I'm trying to play the SWF file of a game since it's a lot smoother.

When I go to the link, it just downloads it and does nothing even when I try to open it. On Google Chrome it would just go to the link and not download. What do I need to download to get this to work? I've downloaded [Adobe Flash Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install pepper-flash on Chromium?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369023/how-do-i-install-pepper-flash-on-chromium)

Answer (score 1):

I too have Ubuntu on my Chromebook and my flash works just fine using the Adobe Flash Plugin for Firefox, which on my system appears to be available at the Ubuntu Software Center.  Yes, I recognize the irony of running the Firefox Web Browser on a Chromebook.  It is both practical and a conversation starter

If you are determined to run chrome/chromium under Ubuntu on a chromebook, you have another alternative.  You should be able to install the [Gnash SWF viewer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/gnash/) or [Lightspark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/lightspark/).

Answer (score 0):

If your swf file is just a video, then `vlc` has a good chance of playing it. Open it up in `vlc` and test it out.

vlc is available on Ubuntu, and I think any Debian-based distro too, but I'm not positive about a chromebook, might take a little more wrangling than just `apt-get install vlc`

Answer (score 0):

You can download .swf file using 'Inspect Element' or 'view source' (Ctrl+u) in browser.
([Guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Download-SWF-Files))
Then use Flash Player 32 Beta Standalone. ([Here](https://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html))
Download 64-bit standalone build for Linux or if you have wine app you can use 32-bit standalone build for Windows. It's really smoother than browser!