# Flash plugin problems on 32-bit Chromium or Opera

Tags: google-chrome, flash, adobe

I have installed (2 days ago) Ubuntu on chromebook via crouton. I think it's 32 bit system. I can't get flash plugin to work, even though I installed it via Ubuntu software center (than deleted it and install it via terminal). I also tried pepper flash - it doesn't work. I tried installing Chrome browser (flash comes with it), but system doesn't let me. 
I need flash plugin for mixcloud, fb games etc.
Any solutions to this? Simple solutions, I'm a Linux newbie. :)

Comment: Chrome does not support 32-bit systems. You can install Chromium.

Comment: Yes, I tried with Chromium, with Firefox, with Opera... Flash doesn't work on either of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pepper-flash on Chromium?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/369023/how-do-i-install-pepper-flash-on-chromium)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Ubuntu Partner repository first.

Go to System Settings -> Software @ Updates -> Other Software and enable Ubuntu Partner there.

An alternative way to add the Partner repository is to run in terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb archive.canonical.com $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Now it has Pepper Flash too. I am using it on 32-bit Chromium.

Comment: I get this:

Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @CicaMarković I updated the answer.

Comment: Terminal says:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise

Comment: There is  pepper flash for 12.04 in Canonical Partner.

Comment: In 12.04 the applet was called differently, not Software & Updates. But everything else is similar.

Comment: I'm sorry, where is System Settings in xfce? It's all new to me.

Comment: I do not have XFCE now. But it must be in the menu.

Comment: Try `software-properties-gtk` in terminal.

Comment: I did that and here what I get: http://3.1m.yt/jd27F0I.png

Comment: Remove all those. There must be Canonical Partner somewhere. If you can't find it, then I will update the aswer with a CLI solution.

Comment: @CicaMarković I added the command.

Comment: I added it with: 
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"

Comment: It is the same. Do not repeat it!

Comment: Your command is safer.

Comment: @CicaMarković So did it work?

Comment: It did! It works on Opera also (I can't type Serbian letters like š, č, ž, ć in Chromium, so I use Opera)! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :D

Comment: Chromium in 12.04 is old and not updated. It is better to use Opera I guess. Please accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left to show other people that the solution works. @CicaMarković

Comment: I think Chrome is the best, but it's not available, so... Opera. Done, I checked it. All the best! Thanks again.